# How to know the number of fragment that are in stack when using Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Navigation Components in my app. From the fist fragment to the last one there are also other fragments, for instance nice. Everytime a user clicks on a fragment is added to the stack. How can I know how many fragments are already added to the stack at one point in time?

Comment: Can you know at all if you are using the Fragment backstack (which the FragmentNavigator uses underneath)?

Comment: What would you need this for?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I know I'm using Fragment backstack since I can get from the last fragment to the first by clicking back back back .... I need that because I want to know when I get to the second, so I can get some actions. Is it even possbile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below method in Activity to get current backstackentry count, where **home_nav_host_fragment** is id of your container *NavHostFragment* in activity.

```
public int getStackCount(){
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.home_nav_host_fragment);
int backStackEntryCount = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
return backStackEntryCount;
}
```

to call this method from fragment you can use
`int count = ((YourActivity)getActivity()).getStackCount();`

Comment: And in fragment, how can I do that?

Comment: ((MyActivity)getActivity()) can help. and provide above count through method.

Comment: Add that to you answer so I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From your Activity, try this:

```
supportFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment?.childFragmentManager?.backStackEntryCount
```

This is particularly helpful if you're trying to get the count from Base Activity since different child activities may have NavHostFragment with different IDs.